# Ibanez Lo Pro Edge set right?

Tags: electric-guitar, setup, bridge

[image: picture of Lo Pro bridge]

I am a beginner with these Floyd Rose bridges; I don't understand if I set the bridge right. I heard that Lo Pro bridges should be inclined a bit, but I have the feeling that it's inclined too much, because when I play it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of tremolo should sit almost flat **unless** you have specific reasons for it to be at an odd angle, eg your style requires max pull-ups...

To pull it back you need to increase the tension on the springs in the back, readjust tuning, adjust the springs and repeat until they are intonated correctly, the trem is at the correct angle, and it feels good to play. If pulling it back makes the string height too low, you need to raise the pivot posts (which on the Zero Point trem doesn't require de-tensioning!)

[Here's Jason Gould's video](https://youtu.be/RwAWeoc0fmA) on Ibanez Zero trem set up.

It's a bit of a pain, but usually only needs doing in such a big way when you change string gauges.

Comment: that holds true for *most* of the tremolo bridges, so this answer does not consider the specific construction of the lo-pro edge, which yes, should be tilted forward a bit like in the picture. [source](https://www.jemsite.com/threads/edge-lo-pro-bridge-set-up.160577/)

Comment: @BCArg - that source states it should not be tilted that far forwards, but in any case, the tilt affects string height and intonation, so is a personal preference

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the specifics of this particular bridge, there are a couple of things that might help you find out if it's *right* assuming that you are happy with the string height.

- Playing through the fretboard to see if there are no dead notes
- Tuning each string and measuring the note on the 12th fret to see if the intonation is correct (ideally it should not deviate from the note of the open string)
- Bending each string a couple of times and measuring the note to see if it has changed
- Similarily, using the whammy bar and measuring the note to see if it has changed

I presume that some of the issues above can be resolved without pivoting the whole bridge, so if you're inclined on experimenting yourself try adjusting other screws as well (don't force it though). But generally I would recommend hiring a professional luthier for the initial set up.

Comment: Thanks, to set the height of the strings there are to screws I heard some people that said that before you turn them you have to remove the spring to remove the tension or the knives are going to be damaged, and I heard other people too that didn't care about it and simply turned the screws, can you help me?

Comment: by adjusting the springs, if I turn clockwise will the back of the bridge go down or up?

Comment: @Milo_666 - turn the screw, you will be able to see the trem move.